# Cordova-Android build error, not able to build cordova android platform

Tags: cordova, build

While running command- "cordova build --release android"

I am getting following error-
Source directory does not exist: [project directory path]\C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-android\bin\templates\platform_www